# gpg: How do we Cross-Sign Keys? (--default-key vs. --local-user)

Tags: gnupg, key-generation

I'm trying to figure out how to cross-sign two keys.  [One reference](https://people.debian.org/%7Eanibal/ksp-dc12/ksp-dc12.html) says we should use:

```
gpg --local-user 0xfedcba98 --edit 0x76543210 sign
gpg --local-user 0x76543210 --edit 0xfedcba98 sign
```

That's an old reference, so I assume we should be using `--edit-key` now.  When I try, I am able to get the first key to sign the second, but the reverse fails....

**Edit**:  After repairing one error having to do with proper quotation of passwords on the command line, I tried Esa's suggestion with `--default-key`, and which appears in his first linked article by Daniel Pecos Martínez.  I was still unable to sign the first key by the second.  I was getting this error:

```
$ gpg --default-key 76543210 --edit-key fedcba98 sign

[snip]

gpg: Warning: not using '76543210' as default key: No secret key
gpg: all values passed to '--default-key' ignored
"MyName <me@mine.com>" was already signed by key fedcba98
Nothing to sign with key fedcba98
```

The solution I found, and this is necessary whether using `--edit-key ... sign`, `--sign-key` or `--quick-sign-key`, is to use `--local-user` as stated in the link above.  `--default-key` does **not** work!

The `man` page says that `--local-user` overrides `--default-key`, so I am guessing that the key database has some notion of default which will not be overridden by `--default-key` but will be by `--local-user`.  I am uncertain, but this may be complicated by the fact that both of my keys have the same UID.  If anyone can confirm and maybe even offer a way to change the database's default, perhaps they might add it in the comments.

I am running:

```
$ gpg --version
gpg (GnuPG) 2.2.4
libgcrypt 1.8.1
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the `0x` prefix when specifying a key, and you could use `--sign-key`.

> `--sign-key name` Signs a public key with your secret key. This is a shortcut version of the subcommand `sign` from `--edit`.

```
gpg --local-user FEDCBA98 --sign-key 76543210
gpg --local-user 76543210 --sign-key FEDCBA98
```

OR

```
gpg --default-key FEDCBA98 --sign-key 76543210
gpg --default-key 76543210 --sign-key FEDCBA98
```

as used e.g. in Daniel Pecos Martínez: [How to rotate your OpenPGP / GnuPG keys](https://danielpecos.com/2019/03/30/how-to-rotate-your-openpgp-gnupg-keys/#signing-the-new-and-old-public-keys). Never stick with the first tutorial you find, as there are plenty of recent documentation available, e.g.

- [GnuPG documentation](https://gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg/), [4.1.3 How to manage your keys](https://gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg/OpenPGP-Key-Management.html#OpenPGP-Key-Management)
- Debian [Keysigning](https://wiki.debian.org/Keysigning)
- Jeff Carouth: [Signing PGP Keys](https://carouth.com/articles/signing-pgp-keys/)
- Francis Chuang: [signing-gpg-keys.md](https://gist.github.com/F21/b0e8c62c49dfab267ff1d0c6af39ab84)

Comment: Esa - I appreciated your links. Unfortunately, in my version of gpg, I had to discover that `--default-key` would not work. See my Edit in the original question.